# JavaScript fade timings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, fade

I have an HTML list of tips and every element in that list is hidden on page load, I then try to fade in 3 random tips after a specified time however the tips fade in at different times dispite all having the same timings set, any ideas why this happens?

Here is my source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.randomtip = function () {
        var pause = 4000;
        var length = $("#tips li").length;
        var temp = -1;

        this.getRan = function () {
            // get the random number
            var ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * length) + 1);

            return ran;
        };
        this.show = function () {
            $("#tips li").fadeOut(800);
            $("#tips li:nth-child(" + getRan() + ")").delay(1000).fadeIn(800);
            $("#tips li:nth-child(" + getRan() + ")").delay(1000).fadeIn(800);
            $("#tips li:nth-child(" + getRan() + ")").delay(1000).fadeIn(800);
        };

        show(); setInterval(show, pause);

    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tips li").hide();
        randomtip();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your script:

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/WPsN7/17/

Your issues are as follows:

1. Fades work on an async, so your fades basically all happen at the same time.  Since the timing is not perfect, they get out of sync quickly.
2. Your random method had no guarantee that it would load unique items.  This could give the same command multiple times to the same element.

To fix this I used jQuery deferreds, a built in functionality to jQuery animations.  That's what the *.promis().done()* is. It's more functional than using the *.fade(interval,callback)* It gaurantees that the callbacks won't fire until the prior command has been done.  This removes the need for *setInterval*, which can cause issues if not well controlled.  Since jQuery has this built in it's not necassary.

Answer (score 0):

After using the code posted by 'Thinking Sites', everything seemed to be okay, but older versions of Internet Explorer didn't support 'indexof' so below is my modified version of the code that does work in older versions of Internet Explorer as well as Chrome and Firefox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var randomtip = function() {
    var pause = 4000;
    var length = $("#tips li").length;
    var temp = -1;

    this.getRan = function() {
        // get the random number
        var result = [];
        while (result.length < 3) {
            var r = Math.round((Math.random() * (length - 1)));
            if (!contains(result, r)) {
                result.push(r);
            }
        }
        return result;
    };

    var fadeout = function() {
        $("#tips li").delay(1500).fadeOut(800).promise().done(fadein);
    };

    var fadein = function() {
        var ran = getRan();
        $("li:eq(" + ran[0] + "),li:eq(" + ran[1] + "),li:eq(" + ran[2] + ")", "#tips").delay(1000).fadeIn(800).promise().done(fadeout);
        };

        fadein();
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tips li").hide();
        randomtip();
    });

    function contains(a, obj) {
        var i = a.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (a[i] === obj) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```